# How to render an innerHTML without adding a tag in Angular

Tags: html, angular, dom, html-rendering

```
<div [innerHTML]="'<b>HEY</b>'"></div>
```

Works well! But the problem is that I don't want the `div` or any other element to add to the page. I just want to render innerHTML content to page. I tried `ng-container` instead of `div` but it is not working. How can I make it happen ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `[outerHTML]` on the div and it will be replaced.

```
<div [outerHTML]="'<b>HEY</b>'"></div>
```